# Loading xgen preview through python

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to load xgen preview  automatically while doing a playblast. The issue I'm currently facing is python doesn't wait for xgen preview to finish loading and runs the next lines and kicks off the playblast and then finishes loading the preview. Is there a way to make python wait for xgen to finish loading before running the next line?

Comment: you could try to evalDeffered your playblast command and refresh the xgen

Comment: I tried that, even tried using `time.sleep()`, it still doesn't wait for xgen to load the preview.

Comment: If evalDeffered doesnt make it. I would go with a custom playblaster.... Manually going from frame to frame and capturing the viewport :/